# Rails 'can't quote array' on query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to make a general query to my navbar that will check if a record containing any of the given values in any of it's fields can be found.

This is the query in my model:

```rb
def self.basic_search(*keywords)
  where("specialties %% ARRAY[:k] or treatments && ARRAY[:k]::varchar[] or
  neighborhood = ANY(ARRAY[:k]) or name ~ ANY(ARRAY[:k])", k: keywords)
end
```

And in my controller I'm passing the `keywords.split(' ')` arguments to this function.

I'm getting an TypeError in my controller that states 'can't quote Array'.

How would I make this query?

I tried change my arrays to match `ARRAY[:k]::varchar[]` following the [Active Record and PostgreSQL - Ruby on Rails Guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_postgresql.html) but it didn't seem to work.

Comment: Why don't you use **ransack gem** for searching? https://rubygems.org/gems/ransack/versions/1.7.0

Comment: My project already has A LOT of dependencies and I'm trying not to add a gem everytime i ran into some problem. But thanks I'll check it out anyway

Comment: Be care with Ransack, it shouldn't be used elsewhere than in the back office, this is a security issue because some database information is exposed in the URL